# Cannot execute PHP script with exec function in PHP 8.0

Tags: php, exec

After migrating PHP from 7.4 to 8.0 the following line that executes a cli tool command stopped working:

```php
exec('php bin/cli init');
```

After investigating the issue it seems that the exec/shell_exec function can execute all available commands but the php command itself (php -v, php -r '...'). Every other command works well. Tested on latest Windows and Mac OS. Safe mode is off. Couldn't find anyone having the same problem out there.

Comment: Is the CLI version of PHP available at all? If so, under what path? Is that path in the `PATH` variable?

Comment: Yes the php command works well in the terminal. It seems to be unavailable when executing in web server context. Using Apache2. @arkascha

Comment: Would you care to answer the questions?

Comment: 1. The cli version is available
2. Under d:/php/php.exe
3. It is in the apache web server context
@arkascha

Comment: You may need the full path to PHP, `/usr/bin/php` or rather, `d:/php/php.exe`. Just because you have access to it in your path doesn't mean the webserver user does.

Comment: You need to consider that the http server process operates in a completely different environment that what you as a person find when opening a console. That is why you have to check these things from the http server's process point of view.

Comment: @arkascha You are right. I had to clear apache's cache because it had cached an old path variable and restarting wasn't affecting it.

Comment: Fine to hear that you solved your problem. Though clearing the cache certainly was _not_ what solved it. The cache does not hold such information. I suspect it holds the resulting output once generated based on the `exec()` call. That would mean that you would _again_ have a cached result in your cache now ...